# Use Azure custom vision model with Node.js

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

i am new to Tensorflow.js so, i don't quite understand it completely.
I have trained an object detection model using Azure Custom Vision ([customvision.ai](https://customvision.ai/)) and as described in there documentation i exported the model for Tensorflow.js for offline use in my Node.js Project.

They have a very brief guide on Github (https://github.com/microsoft/customvision-tfjs) on how to use the model with Tensorflow.js, i tried following the steps but was not able to run it.

If anyone has experience with Tensorflow.js, please help me in this i am stuck on it for past 3 days.

This is the Code that i am trying to execute, i am getting Error

> 'await can only be used with async functions'

even though the loadModelAsync() function is Async.

```
const cvstfjs = require('@microsoft/customvision-tfjs');

let model = new cvstfjs.ObjectDetectionModel();
await model.loadModelAsync('model.json');
const image = document.getElementById('image');
const result = await model.executeAsync(image);
```

Comment: That isn't node.js code, that's JavaScript code in HTML. Where are you stuck Node.js -wise?

Comment: @AKX Thanks for replying. In the Guide here (https://github.com/microsoft/customvision-tfjs). They have provided a code snippet to use the model in Node.js application. But when i try i get the error (import statement cannot be used outside modules). So, i tried using web page snippet. Can you help me in figuring how to run that in Node js

Comment: You will need to use a `require` statement (`const cvstfjs = require('@microsoft/customvision-tfjs');`) instead.

Comment: @AKX i tried but then i get the error (await can only be used with async function) although i checked in the library myself that the function loadModelAsync() is actually Async.

Comment: Yes, the function in which you call async functions with `await` will need to be `async`.

Comment: @AKX It is Async, still the Error is coming

Comment: Add your code in the question then...

Comment: @AKX Ok i just added

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you will need to wrap any `await` calls in an `async` function:

```js
const cvstfjs = require('@microsoft/customvision-tfjs');

async function doThings() {
  let model = new cvstfjs.ObjectDetectionModel();
  await model.loadModelAsync('model.json');
  const image = document.getElementById('image');
  const result = await model.executeAsync(image);
  return result;
}

doThings().then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: This code also gives Error : (node:15392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
    at getNodeRequestOptions (C:\Users\Aakash Bhadana\Desktop\tensorflowjs\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1284:9)
    at C:\Users\Aakash Bhadana\Desktop\tensorflowjs\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1370:19

Comment: Right, that's another problem then. It's unable to load your model from that path. (Based on the exception a full HTTP URL would probably work.)

Comment: Yes you are right, i changed the filename with localhost URL, now the error is for 'document' not defined. How to access HTML image element in Node.js app ?

Comment: The Code snippet has document.getElementById() in between Node.js code, it doesn't makes sense to me ?? Can you help on how to do that.

Comment: You'll need to get the image data from somewhere. Depends on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see ONNX.js  that run ONNX models using JavaScript.
https://github.com/microsoft/onnxjs

[image]